# what's the difference between document.createElement and createDocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Usually, we could use document.createDocumentFragment() to create a DOM piece before append the piece to real DOM.

But we could also use document.createElement() to hold the piece.

So, which one should we use ?